# android: build dual app without usnig third cloning applications

Tags: android, clone

I'm wondering how these dual-app-maker applications works!

I assume that they just do modify the ID of an apk file, build a new one and install it.

So how can I make a dual app without using them?! Is it all about `APKTOOL`?!

Comment: Can you explain it differently and with examples? I don't understand the question.

Comment: lets consider `whastapp`, there is plenty third apps that clone it. how they do that? I think they modify `whatsapp` *apk* and change the id (`com.whatsapp.messenger` => `com.newname.newsuffix`) and it works. if that third apps can do this we could do that as well ( , oder?! ;) ). BUT HOW?!